# Godot static class and argument usage

Tags: c#, godot4

```
private void ChangeText(string name)
{ 
    this.Text = Texts.name;
    _animationPlayer.Play("showtext");
}
```

and the static class code is

```
public static class Texts
{
  public static string Info = "123"; 
  
  public static string Objects = "123";
}
```

I have a static class called Texts that contain strings. I want to trasfer this string names by button arguments, but i cant figure out how to do it properly. For example i have a string thats called "Info" in my Texts class. When i press a button, i pass "Info" as argument in button signal. Then i want my RichTextLable text to change to Texts.Info text.

i tried to create a different variable to make "Texts." + name, but it didn't work obviously

Comment: Do you need to access these texts via property directly? If not, you can store all of them in a dictionary. If yes, you can select the property using reflection (`typeof(Texts).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(null)` assuming static class). To optimize, you can iterate over all the properties using reflection once during initialization and store them to a dictionary.

Comment: If you can't use reflection, you can either roll the property name -> valu manually (e.g. with a switch) or use a different approach (e.g. source generator), but hand-rolling is typically way less effort, especially if this is not a large project where many people would be adding to `Texts`.

Comment: Also, please include your code in your question directly in a code block, do not post images of code, those are hard to copy -> paste -> run locally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using single Properties you could use a dictionary and write a function to retrieve the values you need securly:

```
public static class Texts
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> m_TextValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Info", "123"},
        {"Objects", "123"}
    };

    public static string? GetText(string key)
    {
        string? value = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            if (m_TextValues.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                 value = key;
             }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And in your Button:

```
private void ChangeText(string name)
{
     var text = Texts.GetText(name);
     if (text != null){
         this.Text = Texts.name;
         _animationPlayer.Play("showtext");
     }
     
}
```